# Sobel algorithm implementation

Tags: c, algorithm

I'm really close at implementing this algorithm but there are some problems with my code.

```
int Gx[3][3] = {{ -1, 0, 1 },
                { -2, 0, 2 },
                { -1, 0, 1 }};

int Gy[3][3] = {{ -1, -2, -1 },
                {  0,  0,  0 },
                {  1,  2,  1 }};

unsigned int x, y;
long sumX, sumY;
int SUM;

for (x = 0; x < image->w - 1; x++) {
    for (y = 0; y < image->h - 1; y++) {
        sumX = 0;
        sumY = 0;
        if (x == 0 || x == image->w - 1)
            SUM = 0;
        else if (y == 0 || y == image->h - 1)
            SUM = 0;
        else {
            sumX = (Gx[0][0] * image->pixels[(y-1)*image->w+(x-1)]) + (Gx[0][1] * image->pixels[(y-1)*image->w+(x)]) + (Gx[0][2] * image->pixels[(y-1)*image->w+(x+1)]) +
                   (Gx[1][0] * image->pixels[(y)*image->w+(x-1)]) + (Gx[1][1] * image->pixels[(y)*image->w+(x)]) + (Gx[1][2] * image->pixels[(y)*image->w+(x+1)]) +
                   (Gx[2][0] * image->pixels[(y+1)*image->w+(x-1)]) + (Gx[2][1] * image->pixels[(y+1)*image->w+(x)]) + (Gx[2][2] * image->pixels[(y+1)*image->w+(x+1)]);

            sumY = (Gy[0][0] * image->pixels[(y-1)*image->w+(x-1)]) + (Gy[0][1] * image->pixels[(y-1)*image->w+(x)]) + (Gy[0][2] * image->pixels[(y-1)*image->w+(x+1)]) +
                   (Gy[1][0] * image->pixels[(y)*image->w+(x-1)]) + (Gy[1][1] * image->pixels[(y)*image->w+(x)]) + (Gy[1][2] * image->pixels[(y)*image->w+(x+1)]) +
                   (Gy[2][0] * image->pixels[(y+1)*image->w+(x-1)]) + (Gy[2][1] * image->pixels[(y+1)*image->w+(x)]) + (Gy[2][2] * image->pixels[(y+1)*image->w+(x+1)]);
        }


        SUM = sqrtf((sumX^2) + (sumY^2));

        image->pixels[y * image->w + x] = SUM;
    }
}
```

I used this [implementation](https://blog.saush.com/2011/04/20/edge-detection-with-the-sobel-operator-in-ruby/) which is written in Ruby and turned it into C.

There is a glitch and shouldn't the output be in black and white?

I think that the creator of the example I used, used the wrong multiplications. For example this `(sobel_x[0][0] * img.at(x-1,y-1))`, here he multiplied the index of the sobel array at 0,0 (which is -1) with the pixel of 0,0 since x and y are at the center (1,1) of the pixel array. Instead he should have used `(sobel_x[0][0] * img.at(x+1,y+1))` right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C, the `^` operator is the bitwise xor operator.  There is no power operator, squaring `sumX` is performed by multiplying it with itself: `sumX * sumX`.

Furthermore, you should not stop your loops one short from the edges, the last pixel on each row and the last row are not computed with your current loops.

Defining the coefficient arrays `Gx` and `Gy` as `static const` will allow the compiler to assume their values to be constant and optimize the code without loading these values from the arrays, removing all these multiplications.

Here is a modified version:

```
static const int Gx[3][3] = {{ -1, 0, 1 },
                             { -2, 0, 2 },
                             { -1, 0, 1 }};

static const int Gy[3][3] = {{ -1, -2, -1 },
                             {  0,  0,  0 },
                             {  1,  2,  1 }};

unsigned int x, y;
long sumX, sumY;
int SUM;

for (x = 0; x < image->w; x++) {
    for (y = 0; y < image->h; y++) {
        sumX = 0;
        sumY = 0;     
        if (x > 0 && x < image->w - 1 && y > 0 && y < image->h - 1) {
            sumX = (Gx[0][0] * image->pixels[(y - 1) * image->w + (x - 1)]) +
                   (Gx[0][1] * image->pixels[(y - 1) * image->w + (x)]) +
                   (Gx[0][2] * image->pixels[(y - 1) * image->w + (x + 1)]) +
                   (Gx[1][0] * image->pixels[(y) * image->w + (x - 1)]) +
                   (Gx[1][1] * image->pixels[(y) * image->w + (x)]) +
                   (Gx[1][2] * image->pixels[(y) * image->w + (x + 1)]) +
                   (Gx[2][0] * image->pixels[(y + 1) * image->w + (x - 1)]) +
                   (Gx[2][1] * image->pixels[(y + 1) * image->w + (x)]) +
                   (Gx[2][2] * image->pixels[(y + 1) * image->w + (x + 1)]);

            sumY = (Gy[0][0] * image->pixels[(y - 1) * image->w + (x - 1)]) +
                   (Gy[0][1] * image->pixels[(y - 1) * image->w + (x)]) +
                   (Gy[0][2] * image->pixels[(y - 1) * image->w + (x + 1)]) +
                   (Gy[1][0] * image->pixels[(y) * image->w + (x - 1)]) +
                   (Gy[1][1] * image->pixels[(y) * image->w + (x)]) +
                   (Gy[1][2] * image->pixels[(y) * image->w + (x + 1)]) +
                   (Gy[2][0] * image->pixels[(y + 1) * image->w + (x - 1)]) +
                   (Gy[2][1] * image->pixels[(y + 1) * image->w + (x)]) +
                   (Gy[2][2] * image->pixels[(y + 1) * image->w + (x + 1)]);
        }
        SUM = sqrtf(sumX * sumX + sumY * sumY);
        image->pixels[y * image->w + x] = SUM;
    }
}
```

Note that using a properly defined local pointer to the 2D array `image->pixels` would greatly simplify the code:

```
static const int Gx[3][3] = {{ -1, 0, 1 },
                             { -2, 0, 2 },
                             { -1, 0, 1 }};
static const int Gy[3][3] = {{ -1, -2, -1 },
                             {  0,  0,  0 },
                             {  1,  2,  1 }};
unsigned int x, y;
long sumX, sumY;
pixel_type (*pixels)[image->w] = (void*)image->pixels;

for (x = 0; x < image->w; x++) {
    for (y = 0; y < image->h; y++) {
        sumX = sumY = 0;
        if (x > 0 && x < image->w - 1 && y > 0 && y < image->h - 1) {
            sumX = (Gx[0][0] * pixels[y - 1][x - 1]) +
                   (Gx[0][1] * pixels[y - 1][x]) +
                   (Gx[0][2] * pixels[y - 1][x + 1]) +
                   (Gx[1][0] * pixels[y][x - 1]) +
                   (Gx[1][1] * pixels[y][x]) +
                   (Gx[1][2] * pixels[y][x + 1]) +
                   (Gx[2][0] * pixels[y + 1][x - 1]) +
                   (Gx[2][1] * pixels[y + 1][x]) +
                   (Gx[2][2] * pixels[y + 1][x + 1]);

            sumY = (Gy[0][0] * pixels[y - 1][x - 1]) +
                   (Gy[0][1] * pixels[y - 1][x]) +
                   (Gy[0][2] * pixels[y - 1][x + 1]) +
                   (Gy[1][0] * pixels[y][x - 1]) +
                   (Gy[1][1] * pixels[y][x]) +
                   (Gy[1][2] * pixels[y][x + 1]) +
                   (Gy[2][0] * pixels[y + 1][x - 1]) +
                   (Gy[2][1] * pixels[y + 1][x]) +
                   (Gy[2][2] * pixels[y + 1][x + 1]);
        }
        pixels[y][x] = sqrtf(sumX * sumX + sumY * sumY);
    }
}
```

There is still a major problem: you cannot compute this filter in place, because the modified pixel values are used for the next column and rows.  You must use a temporary array to store the results:

```
static const int Gx[3][3] = {{ -1, 0, 1 },
                             { -2, 0, 2 },
                             { -1, 0, 1 }};
static const int Gy[3][3] = {{ -1, -2, -1 },
                             {  0,  0,  0 },
                             {  1,  2,  1 }};
unsigned int x, y;
long sumX, sumY;
pixel_type (*pixels)[image->w] = (void*)image->pixels;
pixel_type (*dest)[image->w] = malloc(image->h * sizeof(*dest));

for (x = 0; x < image->w; x++) {
    for (y = 0; y < image->h; y++) {
        sumX = sumY = 0;
        if (x > 0 && x < image->w - 1 && y > 0 && y < image->h - 1) {
            sumX = (Gx[0][0] * pixels[y - 1][x - 1]) +
                   (Gx[0][1] * pixels[y - 1][x]) +
                   (Gx[0][2] * pixels[y - 1][x + 1]) +
                   (Gx[1][0] * pixels[y][x - 1]) +
                   (Gx[1][1] * pixels[y][x]) +
                   (Gx[1][2] * pixels[y][x + 1]) +
                   (Gx[2][0] * pixels[y + 1][x - 1]) +
                   (Gx[2][1] * pixels[y + 1][x]) +
                   (Gx[2][2] * pixels[y + 1][x + 1]);

            sumY = (Gy[0][0] * pixels[y - 1][x - 1]) +
                   (Gy[0][1] * pixels[y - 1][x]) +
                   (Gy[0][2] * pixels[y - 1][x + 1]) +
                   (Gy[1][0] * pixels[y][x - 1]) +
                   (Gy[1][1] * pixels[y][x]) +
                   (Gy[1][2] * pixels[y][x + 1]) +
                   (Gy[2][0] * pixels[y + 1][x - 1]) +
                   (Gy[2][1] * pixels[y + 1][x]) +
                   (Gy[2][2] * pixels[y + 1][x + 1]);
        }
        dest[y][x] = sqrtf(sumX * sumX + sumY * sumY);
    }
}
memcpy(pixels, dest, image->h * sizeof(*pixels));
free(dest);
```

Comment: Ok, I removed the -1 from width and height. Now I only get noise.

Comment: @G90: Did you also change `sumX^2` to `sumX * sumX` ?

Comment: Nevertheless even with the simplified version there is an other problem somewhere else cuase i'm still seeing noise.

Comment: @G90: indeed you need a temporary array to store the results because the filter uses 9 pixels at a time.  See my updated code.

Comment: @G90: oops! I originally had used `calloc()`, then figured `malloc` would do but forgot to change the arguments.

Comment: You know instead of going through the hard way you can always create a new image and never mess with the old.

Comment: @G90:  I know that, but you asked the question and were wondering why your code failed... I'm glad you understand the issue.  Did the above code produce the expected results?

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't but your last code and your first using a different image procude the same result. There must be another issue somewher....

Comment: @G90:  You should post a complete verifiable example along with a test image file.

Comment: This is my main http://pastebin.com/m9c3XE4F this is a header http://pastebin.com/Ewjvr6be

Comment: This is an image https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7jVwWbXv2YCQjh4SXB1dWtMWTQ/view

Comment: I downloaded your code and compiled it on OS/X, it works fine.  You might have a problem with the `#pragma push(pack, 1)`  The TGA header is misaligned, reading it with `fread` into a `struct` is non portable.

Comment: Hey chqrlie guess who spend the whole day trying to make it work on windows and it has been working on linux perfect. Why did i even bother? -.- I can't thank you enough!

Comment: @G90: there is a different pragma for the Microsoft compilers. You could also install the MingW suite to use `gcc` on Windows... A better approach is to read the header byte by byte, it is the only portable approach, independent on the size of `short` and the endianness of the CPU that might not be little endian as the file format.

Comment: I installed MingW today and gcc what the compiler I was using.

Comment: I' using `clang` on MacOS, I don't know if the `#pragma` works for `gcc`.  Try parsing the header by hand, it is simple enough.

Comment: I could but I'm supposed to use it as it is. And if it's working on linux why mess with it?

Comment: The program is not portable.  It works on linux for a specific compiler. If you need it to work on Windows, or some other OS, you should modify it to make it more portable, otherwise, just use it where it works.

Comment: It was made to work that way, instead I tried, now knowing, to make it work on windows wasting many hours trying to figure out why  it didn't.

Comment: @G90: You wasted some time but learned a thing or two: beware of `#pragma` lines, a strong indication of non portable code, the same for `fread` to read structures directly from binary files. The lack of a power operator. Finally, question non obvious loop conditions such as `x < image->w - 1`.

Comment: Thank you very much! I need to refresh my C knowledge and go to more advanced C. I'll keep your suggestions in mind!